# "type 'NoneType' is not iterable" error when calling pymssql.connect

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2014, pymssql

I have SQL Server installed on my computer, on the same computer I try to connect to the database using python, but I get the following error:

```
>>> from os import getenv
>>> import pymssql
>>> server = getenv(“КОМП”)
>>> user = getenv(“user”)
>>> password = getenv(“”)
>>> conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, “Test”)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File “<pyshell#6>”, line 1, in <module>
    conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, “Test”)
    File “pymssql.pyx”, line 635, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10734)
    File “_mssql.pyx”, line 1902, in _mssql.connect (_mssql.c:21821)
    File “_mssql.pyx”, line 552, in _mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__ (_mssql.c:5891)
    TypeError: argument of type ‘NoneType’ is not iterable
```

Friends please help. I guess I incorrectly wrote the name of the server, the user ... I attach the screenshot of the input window to the SQL Server database with the login data

[image: login data]

Answer (score 0):

```python
server = getenv("КОМП")
```

is returning `None`, and `pymssql.connect` is choking when it tries to resolve `None` as the server name. From your screenshot looks like you should simply be using

```python
server = "КОМП"
```